# Dapp using react-native and truffle

Tags: truffle, blockchain, react

I have a blockchain dapp which is working fine in web browser.

```
Wallet : Metamask
OS     : Ubuntu 20
Node   : 10.19.0
Npm    : 6.14.4
```

But, I would like to run the dapp in mobile view using truffle react-native. Could you please suggest any sample latest dapp code using truffle react-native?

I already tried truffle suite dapp, but it's not working for me.

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to make a Dapp in React-Native so for that you do not need truffle you can directly implement Web3js in your react-native application by passing the Contract address and ABI.

Comment: Thank you, could you please help me with a sample working code?

Comment: you can refer this: https://github.com/linux08/Dapp